# Division Round Up in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, division, integer-division, ceil

How can I round up when performing division on two `int` values in C++ without using `std::ceil`?

Typically I end up doing something like the following:

```
double res = ceil(a / (double) b);
```

Is there any way I can duplicate the result without using `std::ceil`?

Comment: What are the types of `a` and `b`?

Comment: They are `int`.

Comment: `(int)(a / (double)b + 0.5)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `a` and `b` are both positive, you can avoid floating point completely and get both exact results (no problems with FP rounding) and faster execution time through the classical method:

```
int res = (a + (b - 1)) / b;
```

For negative `a` you don't need any correction - the truncation performed by integer division already has the semantics matching your `ceil` formula; so, if you want a more general case:

```
int res = (a<0 ? a : (a + (b - 1))) / b;
```

Comment: What about the integer overflow here? (if any of a and b are sufficiently large)

Comment: What about negative `b`?

Comment: @LuisMachuca if that's a problem, you can do something like `a / b + !!(a % b)`, which should not pose any problem, but it's probably going to be a bit slower (it has a branch and in general is more convoluted code).

Comment: @norok2: never really thought about that; generally when I use this formula `b` is positive or even known at compile time (typically if I have to e.g. divide by 10 rounding up I just write `(a + 9) / 10`).

Comment: If they are both positive, `(a-1)/b + 1` is better because it cannot overflow.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: nice, never thought about that alternative, maybe you should post that as an answer. *Edit* just noticed, `a` must be *strictly* positive, otherwise for `a == 0` you get +1 instead of 0.

Comment: @norok2 So far, [none](https://godbolt.org/z/vZx3Kx) of the proposed solutions compares equal to `std::ceil` when both `a` and `b` are allowed to be signed.

Answer (score 3):

you could do this

```
double res = (double) (((a % b) == 0) ? (a / b) : (a / b) + 1);
```

basically if there is a remainder, add 1 to the truncated integer result

Comment: Or, more compactly, `a/b + !!(a%b)`.